# Is it possible to know the wear level information of a phone, like SSD have with SMART?

Tags: internal-storage, storage, hardware

Is there a way to find out the media wearout level on an android device? I have a tablet that is acting weird and slow, so I wonder if the internal storage is still ok: it is the Nvidia Sheild (renamed Tegra K1 later on) and probably has eMMC since it's quite old.

I know that a SSD is not the same as a phone storage chip. I read about eMMC and UFS and I am interested about wearout on both generations of storage!

https://www.dignited.com/23879/emmc-or-ufs-mobile-phone-storage/
https://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/what-is-ufs-3-0-storage/

Here's a link to Unix/Linux SE for more info about media wearout:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106678/how-to-check-the-life-left-in-ssd-or-the-mediums-wear-level

I know that one way to estimate the storage wear is to run a storage benchmark app, but I am interested about storage wearout.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

SMART was originally designed for ATA devices and extended to SCSI and PCIe/NVMe later to cover almost the whole range of HDDs/SSDs. Trying to send SMART commands to eMMC, e.g. using [`smartctl`](https://www.smartmontools.org/browser/trunk/smartmontools/smartctl.8.in) would throw error: `Unable to detect device type. Please specify device type with the -d option.`

Unlike SATA or SAS, eMMC communicates over parallel links and has a different [command set](https://linux.codingbelief.com/zh/storage/flash_memory/emmc/emmc_commands.html). One of these commands (`CMD8`) dumps the Extended CSD (Card Specific Data) register which holds card's internal information and device capabilities including ***Life Time*** Estimation and ***Pre EOL*** (End of Life) Estimation. [`EXT_CSD`](https://www.cnx-software.com/2019/08/16/wear-estimation-emmc-flash-memory/#monitoring-flash-health-on-linux) register can be read (requires root) using `mmc` tool from [mmc-utils](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/cjb/mmc-utils.git/):

```
~# mmc extcsd read /dev/block/mmcblk0 | grep -E 'LIFE|EOL'
eMMC Life Time Estimation A [EXT_CSD_DEVICE_LIFE_TIME_EST_TYP_A]: 0x03
eMMC Life Time Estimation B [EXT_CSD_DEVICE_LIFE_TIME_EST_TYP_B]: 0x03
eMMC Pre EOL information [EXT_CSD_PRE_EOL_INFO]: 0x01
```

<sup>* `0x03` indicates health status is estimated between 20% and 30% of the device lifespan.

* `0x01` indicates Normal pre-EOL status.</sup>

Depending on your MMC driver, the above information is also available through [`sysfs` interfaces](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.6/drivers/mmc/core/mmc.c#L781):

```
~# cat /sys/devices/soc/7824900.sdhci/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/{life_time,pre_eol_info}
0x03 0x03
01
```

<sup>* Path may differ depending on eMMC vendor.</sup>

Another option is to read ECSD register from `debugfs`:

```
~# cat /sys/kernel/debug/mmc0/mmc0:0001/ext_csd
```

But [parsing ECSD raw output](https://blog.kylemanna.com/linux/parse-emmc-extended-csd-ecsd-registers-with-python/) is an extra job.

For UFS part I'm not sure at the moment if the health/wear estimation is available through HCI Capabilities Registers or not. Also unlike eMMC, UFS operates over a serial communication link and supports a subset of SCSI commands. So it might be providing SMART (or SMART-like) monitoring system. Someone else may update the answer if some authentic source of information is available.

---

**REFERENCES:**

- [Wear Estimation for Devices with eMMC Flash Memory](https://elinux.org/images/2/2c/Wear_Estimation_for_Devices_with_eMMC_Flash_Memory.pdf)
- [eMMC ELECTRICAL STANDARD (5.1) (JESD84-B51A)](https://www.jedec.org/standards-documents/docs/jesd84-b51)
- [UFS in Linux kernel](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/scsi/ufs.html)
- [UFS Overview](https://jaehyek.github.io/attach/ppt/2016-03-07-eMMC-UFS-About-UFS-1/UFS_Overview_20150821_r0.pdf)

Comment: Wow thanks for the detailed answer about eMMC storage! I assume that these commands are only available on a rooted device...

Comment: @ForeverLearning yes definitely. Without root files in `/dev` and `/sys` aren't accessible.

Comment: It still boggles my mind that there exists a predictable, measurable failure mode that at some point on millions of devices cause them to essentially brick, and yet there is no way to actually measure it because (presumably) it's *ass*umed that nobody is going to keep their devices long enough for it to matter. (planned obsolescence ftl)

Comment: ext4 has (fs-level) lifetime write stats which is shown by `tune2fs -l`. Maybe f2fs has something similar as well but I'm not sure: https://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1602.2/03846.html