# Are there any smartctl similar tools to detect (eMMC/Nand) storage flash failure in advance on non-rooted android?

Tags: storage, hardware, disk-drive

So far, I have two android phones which become kinda brick due to storage failure.

One phone suddenly missed many apps and files one day. And another one does not accept correct lock password one day.

When I try to look into mobie phone storage related topics, I am surprised that so litte info I can find.

I can not even find an app to tell what my phone's storage type and model are. I tried the famous AIDA64, it doesn't really give me anything about my flash drive. I can not even know if it's a NOR, NAND or eMMC.

I have some/many mobiles and some are rooted and some are non-rooted. I am wondering if I can find a general solution to detect flash drive failure in advance so that I can backup properly before it failed to boot and lose data. (I use smartd/smartctl on desktop OS for this purpose)

From my bad experiences, I really don't have any trust on mobile phone storage anymore. I have some other mobiles/pads/tablets broken too without knowinig what the real problem is. I guess they might be due to flash drive failutre as well.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Related https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214029/131553

Comment: @beeshyams just read it. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to know the wear level information of a phone, like SSD have with SMART?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/225078/is-it-possible-to-know-the-wear-level-information-of-a-phone-like-ssd-have-with)

Comment: @IrfanLatif Thank you very much for the reference. That is the closest information I ever found online. But it doesn't answer my question because the solution provided in that question requires `rooted` device. But I have put `non-rooted` device explicitly in the questoin title.